# LDAP Filter for substring? escaping hyphens and parens?

Tags: ldap

I'm doing a lookup from LDAP where I need to search based on a pager number. Our pager numbers could have hyphens or spaces or parens in them.  I'm trying to figure out the search filter I need on my pager field, assuming that my user may or may not know where the parens or hyphens are in the LDAP field.

I am trying to write a filter that will match the last five numeric digits.

Example(the single quotes aren't stored in LDAP, I'm using them here as delimiters):

```
'127 13098'
'125 or (44)8-9622'
'126 (12349)'
```

These would all be possible values in our Pager field in LDAP.

Here's what I have so far:

(&(objectCategory=person)(objectclass=user)(sn=*)(givenname=*)(pager=*" + Pager.Trim() + "))"

This works fine for the first example, but it won't get the middle example, if the user enters just the numeric digits.

Is it going to be possible to write a filter that will find the five digit combination for all three cases, or am I going to need to do multiple searches?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but generally speaking your data should use multi-valued attributes instead of `or`. This will make data management, searching, and auditing much easier, not to mention simplifying application code. It is not scalable to require applications understand the format of the data, and such a practice results in fragile and brittle applications and infrastructures.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, Terry, by "your data should use multi-valued attributes" instead of or.  Are you referring to the data values in my example?   That's something I have no control over.  I'm just trying to search the pager values, not edit or update the values.

Comment: If you have no control over the data, it doesn't matter. I was saying the values of `pager` are better stored in multi-valued attributes, for example `pager: 125` and `pager: (44)8-9622`. In other words, a directory entry would have a `pager` attribute for each value, rather than using the word `or`. But as I say, if you cannot change the format of the data, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure I follow the values, but, you can OR a filter together:

`(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(|(pager=*127 13098*)(pager=125)(pager=126)...))`

The sn and givenName filters shouldn't be necessary unless that's filtering some specific data out. I'd make sure your pager attribute is indexed and has a tuple index in AD.

Comment: I did end up using an OR: (|(pager=*" + Pager.Trim() + ")(pager=*" + Pager.Trim().Substring(0, 1) + "-" + Pager.Trim().Substring(Pager.Trim().Length - 4, 4) + "))